# How to add a custom scroll view using geometry reader inside a scroll view with VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a custom horizontal scroller with Async images and a custom colour scoll bar. This is to be used in a VStack that is inside a scroll view. I have tried to create this but the scroll view height appears to be squashed.

I am trying to create a custom horizontal scroller with Async images and a custom colour scoll bar inside a VStack and Scroll View.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask]. In general, you should include the code you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.